# Cauchy's residue theorem extended to branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, singularity, branch-cuts, branch-points

I'm familiar with Cauchy's residue theorem for calculating integrals in the complex plane. I'm wondering if there's a natural way of extending this to functions which also contain branch cuts. As an example consider
$$
\int_{|z|=1}\sqrt{(2+z)(2+1/z)}dz
$$
This has a pole of order $-\frac{1}{2}$ at the origin with a zero of order $\frac{1}{2}$ at $z=-\frac{1}{2}$ and a branch cut joining the two. How can one evaluate this exactly using contour integration? Is there some sort of combined residue of the whole cut?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is such a residue. Due to the homotopy version of Cauchy's integral theorem, the contour integral only depends on how often and in which direction the contour goes around the cut. So we could simply define the Residue as the integral over a sufficiently large circle going around the branch cut once, divided by $2\pi\mathrm i$. The issue is that for isolated singularities, we were able to obtain this integral by doing a Laurent expansion around the singularity. We can't do this for a branch cut, so I don't know how to actually calculate this residue. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: The integrand has four branch points: $0, -1/2, -2, \infty$. There are two branches which are analytic on $D = \{z: 1/2 < |z| < 2\}$. If the chosen branch is $f(z) = \sqrt {2 + z} \sqrt {2 + 1/z}$, where $\sqrt z$ is the principal value, then $\int_{|z| = 1} f(z) \, dz$ is equal to $2 \pi i$ times the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$ on $D$. The coefficient is
$$c_{-1} = \frac 2 {3 \pi} (5 E(m) - 3 K(m)),$$
where $m = 1/4$ and $K$ and $E$ are the elliptic integrals.