# Contour integration $I = \int_{| z | = 1} \frac{z^2+1}{z\sqrt{z (z-a)(z-1/a)}} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Please compute this integral:

$$I = \int_{| z | = 1} \frac{z^2+1}{z\sqrt{z (z-a)(z-1/a)}} dz$$

where $\vert a \vert < 1$. I have tried to construct dogbone integral or make a large circle $C_R$ with $R \to \infty$ in order to calculate the residue value at infinite. However, I do not know how to proceed. My description might be confusing, and it does not show much work that I have done but this is because I am still very uncertain about branch cut and square root in the function.

Comment: Why do you think it is computable by residues? I would expect the result to be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Yes.  I do find out an expression in elliptic integral as well. However, I just want to know that are there any possible ways of constructing a contour and use Residue theorem to compute an exact value of this integral? If no, how can we know that there are no ways to construct such contour?

Comment: This is because we have 4 square root branch points: $0,a,1/a$ and $\infty$. To make the things well-defined, we need introduce branch cuts: for instance, one joining $0$ and $a$ (it will be inside the circle $C$), the other joining $1/a$ and $\infty$ (this one is outside). Now by shrinking or expanding the contour we can only collapse $C$ to one of these branch cuts instead of isolated singular points where one would be able to compute residues.

Comment: See the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938404). If $0 < a < 1$ and $f(z)$ is the branch of the integrand which is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus ([0, a] \cup [1/a, \infty))$ and for which $f(z) \in (0, i \infty)$ when $z \in (a, 1/a)$, then
$$\int_{|z| = 1} f(z) \, dz =
2 \pi i c_{-1} =
\frac {8 (E(m) - K(m))} {\sqrt a},
\quad m = a^2.$$

Comment: @Start wearing purple  So I wonder that are there any other cases that contour integration won't work? because I have learned that this method is powerful.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you so much.